# Show that two consecutive integers do not share any prime as factor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can assume a smaller subset of positive integers, as the same result would hold for the bigger set.
Let the two positive integers be $x, x+1$, and one would be even and the other odd. So, there cannot be a common prime factor. 
The above approach seems incomplete, although definitely there would be no common factors for an even and an odd number. If there were a simple proof that is rigorous too.

Comment: Wouldn't a similar approach work as in the proof of infinite primes? You decompose $x$ as a product of $p_1,\ldots,p_n$, and then $x+1 = p_1\cdots p_n + 1$, so none of the prime factors divide $x+1$?

Comment: **Hint:** Just prove that $(n,n+1)=1.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That proof is no proof at all. The number $6$ is even, the number $9$ is odd and they share a common prime factor: $3$.

Here's a proof: if $p$ is prime and $p$ divided both $n$ and $n+1$, then $p$ divides their difference, that is, $p$ divides $1$, which is impossible.

Comment: Although not in this OP domain. In linear algebra if take the concept of linear combinations, then if $p\mid n, p\mid n+1$, then what is significance of $p \mid $ all linear combinations of $n, n+1$. I am asking as beginner.